# Geometric properties of solutions of Hamiltonian system

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, hamiltonian-mechanics

***Context :*** We are interested in the following dynamic with state $(q,\varphi)$

$$
\dot q = \varepsilon F(q,\varphi), \quad \dot \varphi = \omega(q) + \varepsilon G(q,\varphi)
$$
($\varepsilon >0$ is small so that we have a splitting system in the sense slow/fast variable and $F$ is a $\varphi$-periodic smooth vector field)

---

***Problem:*** Now consider an augmented system.
Let $(q,\varphi,p,p_{\varphi})\in \mathbb{R}^n\times S^1\times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ be a solution of a Hamiltonian system given by the Hamiltonian $H$
defined by
$$
H(q,\phi,p,p_{\varphi}) = p_{\varphi} \omega(q) + \varepsilon K(q,\varphi,p,p_{\varphi})
$$
where $K(q,\varphi,p,p_{\varphi})$ is **homogeneous** of degree $1$ in $(p,p_{\varphi})$.

Moreover $K$ is periodic with respect to $\varphi$ ( $\dot \varphi = \omega(I) + \varepsilon G(q,\varphi)$).

We define

$$
\bar h(q,p) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{K(q,\varphi,p,p_{\varphi}=0)-1}{\omega(q)} d\varphi
$$

It appears that $\bar h$ defines a **new Hamiltonian** system in 
$(q,p)$, homogeneous of degree $1$ in $p$.

We look for the solution at $\mathbf{\bar h = h_0}$. 
(Note that if $h_0=0$, $\bar h$ defines a Finsler metric.)

***Question:*** - What can we say about the solutions when $h_0$ is varying ? 
Does these solutions for different values of $h_0$ may verify some geometric properties ? like homothetic (due to the homogeneity of $K$) ?

Comment: If $\dot{\phi} = \omega(q)$ doesn't that imply that $K$ does not depend on $p_{\phi}$? Isn't your Hamiltonian $H(q,\phi, p, p_{\phi}) = p_{\phi} \omega(q) + K(q,\phi, p)$?

Comment: Yes, I forgot terms in $\dot \varphi$

Comment: So basically you have a time-dependent periodic perturbation of a integrable Hamiltonian written in action-angle coordinates? And you want to apply some averaging technique? By the way, the homogeneity of the Hamiltonian suggests a conservation law, which leads to another Hamiltonian that commutes with this one, so you may be able to reduce the system a bit... What does Arnold's book on mechanics say? He has discussed averaging there...

Comment: Yes this is in this framework of perturbation theory.
The conservation law, you mean that looking solutions on the energy $H=\varepsilon$ leads to $p_{\varphi} = (1-K(q,\varphi,p,p_{\varphi}))/\omega$ and locally, we can find a function $h$ such that  $p_{\varphi} = -\varepsilon h(q,\varphi,p)$. This is what you mean ?